# When can I be sure a constexpr global variable will be "forgotten", like a C macro?

Tags: c++, macros, constexpr

I want to use a global `constexpr` variable:

```
constexpr int foo = 123;
```

instead of a C macro:

```
#define FOO (123)
```

in some code I'm writing. I would like to be guaranteed the same behavior, in the sense that this will not take up space in memory at runtime, nor will it be visible/exist in the compiled object code (that is, its value will be used as an immediate where relevant).

Can I get this guarantee at all? Under some conditions? Assume, of course, I'm not trying to use x's address or any such funny business.

Comment: Note that a global `constexpr` variable implicitly has internal linkage, so there should be no need for the compiler to emit a symbol for it.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Build error if symbol is present? Try using a tool to dump symbols and check as separate build step, maybe.

Comment: It probably depends on the compiler.  I would say that, if you're trying to intentionally hide symbols in built executables, the macro approach is your best bet.

Comment: `constexpr` is a declaration of intent. I believe that there is no guarantee in spec that its value will not land in any static variables or so.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I get this guarantee at all? Under some conditions? Assume, of
>   course, I'm not trying to use x's address or any such funny business.

Yes, the compiler will *almost* always substitute `foo` for the number at compile time with no extra memory See [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).
Almost certainly, the compiler will *only* allocate memory to `foo` if you take it's address.

And, from the link on [**([expr.const])**](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#1)... we see a note:

> Note: Constant expressions can be evaluated during translation.

And, and as far as most C++ compilers I know goes, they will evaluate and fold expressions where possible.

---

Using [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org), this code (without taking the address of `foo`)...

```
constexpr int foo = 123;
int x(){
    int b = 5 + foo;
    return b;
}
```

Without optimization flags, the Code generated was:

```
x():
        movl    $128, %eax
        ret
```

=======================================

But this code... (taking the address of `foo`)

```
constexpr int foo = 123;
int x(){
    int b = 5 + reinterpret_cast<long>(&foo);
    return b;
}
```

generated....

```
x():
        movq    foo, -8(%rsp)
        movl    foo, %eax
        addl    $5, %eax
        ret
foo:
        .long   123
```

---

NB: Why I have used *may* instead if *will* is because the C++ standard doesn't force compilers to do so, (but they almost certainly do so, some are free not to do so for their specific constraints).

Comment: But that's not all. The question is whether some tricky code might peek at my symbol table and find an entry for foo.

Comment: @einpoklum, I've substantially updated my answer to be more elaborate

Comment: The second example does not take foo's address (and the `reinterpret_cast` is really just a `static_cast`, except that it prevents the result from being a constexpe).

Comment: You got your +1, and yet - is this just de-facto behavior? Seems like it is, according to @c-smile's comment.

Comment: @einpoklum the assumptions this answer is making **ONLY** hold on platforms that allow for constants in the instruction stream of `int` size. On many RISC platforms, the constant size is often smaller than word size; often half word size. In those cases the compiler is free to create a symbol for the constant or folded constant so that the value can be loaded.

Comment: @WhiZTiM almost none of this holds to be true on RISC platforms because the instruction sets may not allow for full width constants.

Comment: @Mgetz, True, Thanks. I have updated my answer to **almost always**.

Comment: @M.M, answer has been overhauled, with a footnote too. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard does not make any guarantees about taking space in memory at runtime, or the contents of object files.

`constexpr int foo = 123;` at namespace scope means that `foo` has internal linkage, and in each translation unit that this line is visible, there is an object with static storage duration, of `sizeof(int)` bytes.

The compiler is permitted, but not required, to optimize out this storage if the output of the program does not depend on whether the storage actually exists.  (This is called the [as-if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule).

An example of where the storage probably would **not** be optimized out would be if you had a function:

```
int const *bar() { return &foo; }
```

---

In practice:

- it is *very likely* that if `foo` is not [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) then it will not occupy memory at runtime.
- it is *very likely* that `foo`'s name will not appear in an object file, since it has internal linkage.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be guaranteed the same behavior, in the sense that this will not take up space in memory at runtime, nor will it be visible/exist in the compiled object code (that is, its value will be used as an immediate where relevant).

```
constexpr int foo = 123;
```

will be equally seen as `123` whenever the compiler hits it. No extra memory, nothing fancy.

So yes, it's completely equivalent with the preprocessors replacement for

```
#define FOO (123)
```

Comment: So there will be no trace of foo in the compiled code?

Comment: @einpoklum _"So there will be no trace of foo in the compiled code?"_ No, there won't be. Not sure about debugging mode, but in release builds that symbol will be stripped.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is incorrect. If the address of foo is taken, it can't be optimized out.